# SVN & Xcode issue with files path & update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svn, version-control

I have a project that needs to be committed using svn. When a user commits the project and i update it on my system the files do get added or updated in my project but the reference path to those files do not change.

Eg:
the path of file ABC.swift in user1's system is user1/application/Project1/ABC.swift

so when i update the project in my system the files do get updated but the reference path remains the same as above whereas the path should change as per my project in my system.

Check the image below for the same situation with storyboard.
The path doesn't change and i get red marked files stating that the file is missing. Actually the file is there in the project but the relative path does't get updated.

[image]

I have been struggling on this since long.

Answer (score 1):

You have absolute paths in your project, they need to be changed to be relative paths, either to group or project.  To do this, open up the right hand tab view in Xcode, and select the red file.  Choose the first icon in the top row of icons on the right hand tab view. Under Identity and Type->Location, you'll see the name of the file with a small folder icon.  Click on the small folder icon and locate the file so the red file turns black. Then, just above the small folder icon, there's a popup menu for Location.  Change this to "Relative to Group" or "Relative to Project" Repeat for all red files.  Commit your project, and get your co-worker to update theirs.  That should fix your problem.